# Поиск строки в строке и замена её

Tags: javascript

```
    msg.replace('{:curQuantity}', quant);
    msg.replace('{:newQuantity}', '12');
    msg.replace('{Date1}', startDay);
    msg.replace('{Date2}', endDay);
```

Смысл таков, заменить в данной строке все данные вхождения на значение. Но почему-то replace() менять не особо захотел.
За строку можно взять данное значение:

```
var msg = '{:curQuantity} bottles currently in stock. Order {:newQuantity} bottles and your items will ship {Date1} – {Date2}';
```

Comment: `msg = msg.replace('{:curQuantity}', quant);`  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: @Igor спасибо, уже разобрался. Забыл о состоянии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался... Ввёл ещё одну переменную, и в ней сохранял состояние.

```
    var message = msg.replace('{:curQuantity}', quant);
    message = message.replace('{:newQuantity}', '22');
    message = message.replace('{Date1}', startDay);
    message = message.replace('{Date2}', endDay);
```